# My Question about DHCP over VPNs was put on hold for being off topic, but it's on topic

Tags: support, off-topic, moderators

[How are VPN Clients given IP addresses when they connect to VPN Routers such as VyOS? (How do Virtual IP Address Pools fit in?)](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46877/how-are-vpn-clients-given-ip-addresses-when-they-connect-to-vpn-routers-such-as)

- It's about theory of protocols used to operate a network
- Can we agree that VPNs aren't really used in home networking? (You know besides Network Engineers practicing for production networks.)
- DHCP is basically layer 3 with a little layer 2 involved via ARP.
- VyOS Router which is Enterprise Class/has paid support options.

(Note on my original post I avoided mentiong VyOS, because I was trying to talk generically since it was more of a theoretical concept that I wanted clarification on. Plus the vocabulary/concept is applicable to multiple vendors, I edited the post to specify that VyOS is the real product I'm inquiring about.)

Answer (score 2):

I reopened your question after your edits. You have a couple of misconceptions:

1. *Can we agree that VPNs aren't really used in home networking? (You know besides Network Engineers practicing for production networks.)*

   That is incorrect. Many home users use VPNs
2. *DHCP is basically layer 3 with a little layer 2 involved via ARP.*

   That is incorrect. DHCP is not layer-3, and it has nothing at all to
   do with ARP.